# Beginner wanting to use optaplanner to solve Vehicle Routing Problem

Tags: jhipster, optaplanner, optaweb-vehicle-routing

I am doing a project which requires to use optaplanner for constraint solving and optimization. Can anyone tell me as to how one can get started? I have read the documentation on the optaplanner website but they are not really helpful. I need proper steps as to how one can do the setup(preferable if anyone has done it in Jhipster-Ionic) and how one needs to proceed to solve the vrp problem. There is also optaweb vehicle-routing but how does one use it?

I am able to run the optaplanner-examples on my windows system. Apart from that I have no clue as to how one should proceed.

Comment: Why jhipster tag?

Comment: Actually I am developing my project in Jhipster-Ionic that is why used the tag.

Comment: IMHO the OptaPlanner is having a nice and comprehensive documentation. Like @Radovan Synek mention below the the OptaPlanner can be integrated with multiples frameworks. If you want to use it with JHipster I will say to get started with the SpringBoot integration https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/quickstart/spring-boot/spring-boot-quickstart.html

Answer (score 0):

Please see the [Quickstarts chapter in the documentation](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/quickstart/overview/overview-quickstarts.html), which describes integration with both Quarkus and Spring Boot, as well as running OptaPlanner in a standard Java program without any frameworks.

The closest example of the VRP integration into a (Quarkus-based) web application is the [vehicle routing quickstart](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner-quickstarts/tree/stable/use-cases/vehicle-routing).

Please note that the `optaweb-vehicle-routing` is no longer maintained.

Comment: I ran the quickstarts file. When I launched the vehicle routing and clicked on solve it gives the error: "Start solving failed (403: CORS Rejected - Invalid origin)."
But a few months back when I had tried to run and solve it did not give this error. Any idea as to why this is happening?

Comment: I tried running the quickstart both in the Quarkus dev mode and as a packaged application and haven't seen any issues.
Would you kindly share some steps to reproduce the problem?